# Saving and updating records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have made two SQL statements as I was unable to figure out how to solve my problem. One is called `Product_GetID` and the other `Product_SaveRecord`.  I wanted the save record to read and see if there was an ID entered in a field in a VB front end and if there was not, it would assign one for it, but I was unable to figure this out.  It works, but I know there should be a better way to do this.

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Product_GetID] 

AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @NewProductID as int
/* Get New Record */
SET @NewProductID = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ProductID) + 1, 1) FROM Product)
SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ProductID) + 1, 1) AS NewIDNo FROM Product
INSERT INTO Product (ProductID, CategoryID, Description, Price)
VALUES        (@NewProductID, 0, '', 0) 
END


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Product_SaveRecord] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@ProductID as int, @CategoryID as tinyint, @Description as varchar(80),       @FullDescription as         varchar(240), @Price as decimal(8, 2), @MarkupPer as   decimal(8, 2), @LabourHours as decimal(8, 2), @LabourRate as decimal(8, 2), @Stock as integer

AS
BEGIN

/* Update Record */
UPDATE Product SET CategoryID = @CategoryID,
Description = @Description, 
FullDescription = @FullDescription, 
Price = @Price,
MarkupPer = @MarkupPer,
 LabourHours = @LabourHours,
LabourRate = @LabourRate,
 Stock = @Stock
 WHERE ProductID = @ProductID
END
```

Answer (score 7):

## **Nitpicks**

Why is this indented?

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Product_GetID]
```

This indentation is inconsistent:

```
UPDATE Product SET CategoryID = @CategoryID,
Description = @Description, 
FullDescription = @FullDescription, 
Price = @Price,
MarkupPer = @MarkupPer,
 LabourHours = @LabourHours,
LabourRate = @LabourRate,
 Stock = @Stock
 WHERE ProductID = @ProductID
END
```

---

The comments are just noise, it's pretty obvious from the way the code reads to figure out what it does. Especially comments like this:

```
/* Update Record */
UPDATE Product SET CategoryID = @CategoryID,
```

---

Vertical white space would make your code easier to read. For example:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Product_SaveRecord] 
@ProductID as int, @CategoryID as tinyint, @Description as varchar(80),       @FullDescription as         varchar(240), @Price as decimal(8, 2), @MarkupPer as   decimal(8, 2), @LabourHours as decimal(8, 2), @LabourRate as decimal(8, 2), @Stock as integer
```

Compare to:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Product_SaveRecord] 
    @ProductID as int, 
    @CategoryID as tinyint, 
    @Description as varchar(80),       
    @FullDescription as varchar(240), 
    @Price as decimal(8, 2), 
    @MarkupPer as   decimal(8, 2), 
    @LabourHours as decimal(8, 2), 
    @LabourRate as decimal(8, 2), 
    @Stock as integer;
```

Also, consistency would be good in how you capitalize keywords. Either do all caps, or all lower caps; it's less confusing that way.

---

**End your SQL statements**

Not using the delimiter `;` throughout your query makes it more difficult to understand the logic of your code. Use `;` and even `GO` if need be. MS SQL Server is forgiving on syntax errors (try PostgreSQL for fun), that doesn't mean you shouldn't follow good practices of ending statements properly.

---

## **Your question**

You're trying to insert a row and then use the ID of the row you inserted. [There is an easier way to do this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx) using `@@IDENTITY` in Transact-SQL.

Here would be a simpler way to do this your way, with above advice applied:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Product_GetID] 
    @ProductID AS INT, 
    @CategoryID AS TINYINT, 
    @Description AS VARCHAR(80),       
    @FullDescription AS VARCHAR(240), 
    @Price AS DECIMAL(8, 2), 
    @MarkupPer AS DECIMAL(8, 2), 
    @LabourHours AS DECIMAL(8, 2), 
    @LabourRate AS DECIMAL(8, 2), 
    @Stock AS INTEGER
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Product (CategoryID, Description, Price)
VALUES (0, '', 0);
UPDATE Product 
SET CategoryID = @CategoryID,
Description = @Description, 
FullDescription = @FullDescription, 
Price = @Price,
MarkupPer = @MarkupPer,
LabourHours = @LabourHours,
LabourRate = @LabourRate,
Stock = @Stock
WHERE ProductID = @@IDENTITY;
END
```

## ***BUT...***

Why do you not simply insert your parameters within one single `INSERT` transaction?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Product_GetID] 
    @ProductID AS INT, 
    @CategoryID AS TINYINT, 
    @Description AS VARCHAR(80),       
    @FullDescription AS VARCHAR(240), 
    @Price AS DECIMAL(8, 2), 
    @MarkupPer AS DECIMAL(8, 2), 
    @LabourHours AS DECIMAL(8, 2), 
    @LabourRate AS DECIMAL(8, 2), 
    @Stock AS INTEGER
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Product(
    CategoryID,
    Description, 
    FullDescription, 
    Price,
    MarkupPer,
    LabourHours,
    LabourRate,
    Stock
) VALUES (
    @CategoryID,
    @Description, 
    @FullDescription, 
    @Price,
    @MarkupPer,
    @LabourHours,
    @LabourRate,
    @Stock
);
END
```